# Microsoft SQL Server - restricting subqueries

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, subquery

This is mostly a curiosity question. I've just experienced a situation where on a test database I had the following query:

```
update table 
set column1 = 1 
where column2 in (1,2)
```

But this kept executing with the error that subquery returned more than one value.

Now I checked to make sure I did not have multiple identity keys or that the 'in' values were unique. so for all intents and purposes this should not have happened.

Checking on the LIVE copy of the database, same query did not have an issue. Hence, finally, my question is:

What can you do to the Microsoft SQL Server settings or database structure that would create such a scenario?

Comment: Does your table have an update trigger on it?  I am guessing that it does and it assumes that `inserted` or `deleted` has only one row in it.

Comment: So... the only way you should run into PK violation is if the Column1 is a part of the composite PK or PK itself. The query seems straight forward: Update column1 and set it to (1) if you find value (1) or (2) in the column2 within the same tuple. I am guessing your test DB has different starting records that your production. Can you copy the production values over to your test DB and run it again ?

Comment: @Milan How did you get from "subquery returned more than one value" to "PK violation"?

Comment: Ahhh, did someone edited the original post? I must have totally misread the question then. Sorry about that. Yes, the trigger could definitely cause such scenario. Also I wonder what would happen in the 2nd column would be computed column with some dependency on the 1st one...? Something I need to try :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What can you do to the Microsoft SQL Server settings or database structure that would create such a scenario?

As mentioned in comments you probably have poorly written trigger. Sample scenario:

```
CREATE TABLE aud(column2 INT, comment NVARCHAR(150));
CREATE TABLE tab(column1 INT, column2 INT);

INSERT INTO aud(column2) VALUES (1),(2),(3);
INSERT INTO tab(column1, column2) VALUES (0,1),(-1, 2), (-2,3);
GO

CREATE TRIGGER trg_tab_i ON tab 
FOR UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
   UPDATE aud
   SET comment = 'Changed value ...'
   WHERE column2 = (SELECT column2 FROM inserted);
END
GO


UPDATE tab
SET column1 = 1 
WHERE column2 in (1,2);
```

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure trg_tab_i, Line 5 [Batch Start Line 19]
>
> **Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.**

```
UPDATE tab
SET column1 = 1 
WHERE column2 in (1);
-- (1 row(s) affected)
-- (1 row(s) affected)
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=491a2a2daa2ead100f825f836a8391ff)**

When only one row is affected everything works.

Comment: Thanks. It turned out that our software vendor was testing a trigger for a custom functionality and i was not aware it made it to our _test DB. (my colleague was aware of it but he never thought that it was a trigger at fault)