# I have an insert with a select and it returns me this error

Tags: sql-server

```
insert into Pedidos (numero, NumeroTrans ,fecha,tipo ,Cliente ,Vendedor, 
terminoS , Descuento ,GrupoImpuesto ,Nulo , Total, MontoImpuesto, SubTotal, 
Almacen,CurrencyID , CreatedBy ,OnHoldStatus ,DocHour,Cash,DateCreaty
)
SELECT * FROM PEDIDO_WEB
```

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure fechawe, Line 9
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
>   The statement has been terminated.

Comment: Probably poorly written trigger on  Pedidos table

Comment: There's no such thing as a SELECT trigger, so wouldn't the trigger have to be on `Pedidos`?    The error is occurring in `Procedure fechawe` according to the error message.   What's the code in that procedure?

Comment: @TabAlleman Of course that on insert table. Thanks :)

Comment: Anyway try to avoid SELECT *, but write all the field names

Comment: [Poor trigger example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45575610/microsoft-sql-server-restricting-subqueries/45583621#45583621)

Comment: @thank you very much